Are PA and Counting Theory synonymous\bi-interpretable?
The following question is whether $\sf PA$ is synonymous or even bi-interpretable with a theory about counting objects in finite sets.
Counting Theory:
$\textbf{Logic:}$ Bi-sorted first order logic with equality. Lower cases stand for numbers, upper cases for sets of numbers.
$\textbf{Extralogical Primitives: }  <, \in, \#$
Syntax: $<$ only occurs between lower cases, $\in$ from lower to upper case. $\#$ a total binary function whose first argument is a lower case and the second argument is an upper case and the value is a lower case, so $\#(x,S)=y $ is to be read as: the count of $x$ in $S$ is equal to $y$.
Define: $x > y \iff y < x$
Define: $x \leq y \iff x < y \lor x=y$
Define: $x \not > y \iff \neg \, x > y$
$ \textbf{Axioms:}$

$ \textbf{Sorting: } x \neq Y$

$ \textbf{Order:} \  x < y  < z \to x < z \land x  \neq y$

$ \textbf{Finiteness:}  \ y \in X \to   \exists \, l,u \in X \forall m \in X :  l \leq m  \leq u    $

$\textbf{Sets: }  \forall n \exists! X \forall m (m \in X \leftrightarrow m \not > n \land \phi)$, if $X$ is not free in formula $\phi$

$\textbf {Counting: } \\ x \in S \to \# (x,S)= \sup^+  \{\# (y,S) \mid y \in S \land y < x \} \\ x \notin S \to \#(x,S)=0$


Where: $\sup^+ X = y \iff \\ \forall z: (\forall m \in X \, (m < z) \land z > 0) \leftrightarrow y \leq z $

$\textbf{Multiplicity: } \exists x: x=x \land \forall x \exists y: x < y$

Define: $\operatorname {Count}(S)=\{\#(x,S)    \mid   x \in S  \}$
Now we can define the cardinality operator on sets $||$ as:
$|S|= \sup \operatorname {Count}(S)$
Where: $\sup X = y \iff \forall z:  \forall m \in X \, (m \leq z)   \leftrightarrow y \leq z $
Having cardinality defined we can easily define addition $a + b=c$ as $c$ being the cardinality of  the set union of some set of cardinality $a$ and some disjoint set from it of cardinality $b$. Mulitplication $a \times b=c$ is definable also,   as the supermum of a set of cardinality $b$ whose first element is $a$ and such that for each element $k$ of it the element of the next higher count in it is $k+a$. The successor function is the $+1$ function, and all rules of $\sf PA$ would follow.
For the other direction $\sf PA$ can interpret this theory by having the naturals be the odd numbers, and have the sets of the naturals to be the even numbers that are doubles of numbers that have binary expansions only containing $1$ at odd positions, then we use the Ackermann interpretation to define $\in$. So for example $\{1,3\}=101 \times 10; \{3,5\}= 10100 \times 10$ [to avoid confusion the zero-one numbers are in binary]. We keep equality relation, the $<$ relation is the usual defined $<$ of $\sf PA$ but restricted to the odds, and $\#(x,S)$ is definable recursively in $\sf PA$ of course here restricted to odds and the abovementioned evens standing for sets of them.

Can $\sf PA$ and Counting Theory be synonymous? Or even bi-interpretable?

To the vulgar eye of mine, Counting Theory is no   less a natural theory of arithmetic than $\sf PA$, since our basic understanding of the naturals actually arose from counting the order of objects in finite sets. Counting by fingers is a life example of it! So, it would be nice to know if these two natural theories of arithmetic are synonymous.
PS: a definition of the $\in$ relation of $\sf CT$ in $\sf PA$ that ranges over all evens was given in the answer by Lumsdaine as: the number $n \in_G m$ , if and only if,  $m$ is even and the $[(n-1)/2 \, +1]^{th}$ digit of the binary representation of $m$ is $1$. Where the $i^{th}$ digit is the coefficient of $2^i$. This way $n$ must be an odd number to be an $\in_G$ element of $m$.

A side note: you write “our basic understanding of the naturals actually arose from counting the order of objects in finite sets”.  One the one hand, we really don’t know this for sure — the basic arithmetic of naturals goes back well beyond periods where we have detailed evidence.  On the other hand, the more commonly imagined version (as told in various versions of the fable of Bo Peep) starts from counting numbers of things — starting by counting cardinality, not order.

On the other hand, your axiomatisation is interestingly reminiscent of (perhaps deliberately inspired by?) some treatments from the very early days of set theory, which use ordered sets as a starting point from which to axiomatise the natural numbers and finiteness, e.g. Huntington 1905 The Continuum as a Type of Order, https://doi.org/10.2307/2007245, an early English-language treatment bringing together ideas from Hausdorff and Dedekind.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine, of course I might be mistaken about the history of the matter, but I meant we when first taught about numbers in our early development the easiest way was to count by our fingers, and this theory tries to grasp this practice. Thanks for the reference about ordered sets and its role in understanding the naturals and finiteness.

Minor note: it seems to me you have some notational (and possibly logical) gaps in your definition of CT. For example, you use the symbols $≤$ and $≯$ without defining them, although it's fairly obvious how they should be defined. Also, I assume you (probably) intend $<$ to be a total order on numbers, but it's not clear to me that your axioms imply that. Your order axiom implies transitivity and irreflexivity of $<$ (at least assuming that there's no largest number!), but I'm not sure it implies asymmetry and it definitely doesn't imply totality: an empty relation trivially satisfies it!

…also, if $<$ is not necessarily a total order, it's not clear to me that your $\sup^+$ is unique.

@IlmariKaronen, it implies both asymmetry and totality. You cannot have $a < b$ and $b < a$ since by axiom of Order you'll have $a < a$ which is forbidden. For totality, take any two objects $a,b$ we construct the set ${a,b}$ but by then either $a \leq b$ or $b \leq a$ by the axiom of finiteness, so they are comparable. $<$ is a well ordering because of the lower bounds on sets that Finiteness confers.

@IlmariKaronen,  thanks for turning my attention to the multiplicity issue, I've added an axiom asserting it, definitions also added.

@IlmariKaronen, just wanted to add that although I've added the multiplicity axiom but in reality it is redundant, but I've added it for clarity purposes. The reason is $\exists x: x=x$  is a logical axiom since in multi-sorted logic it is usually assumed that the domains of each sort should not be empty; that said, the sentence $\forall x \exists y: x < y$  would follow from the axiom of Counting.

@PeterLeFanuLumsdaine, regarding basing arithmetic on cardinality of finite sets, I've made recently such a formulation see this posting, also see comments below the given answer to it, there is a version of axiomatization that is mutually interpretable with PA which is even simpler than the current one.

For bi-interpretability, it seems like you’ve mostly answered the question yourself. You’ve described interpretations $\newcommand{\PA}{\mathsf{PA}}\newcommand{\CT}{\mathsf{CT}}\newcommand{\S}{\mathsf{S}}\newcommand{\N}{\mathsf{N}}F : \PA \to \CT$, interpreting the base sort $\N_\PA$ of $\sf PA$ as the “numbers” $\N_\CT$ of $\CT$, and $G : \CT \to \PA$, interpreting $\N_\CT$ as odd numbers of $\PA$ and the “sets” $\S_\CT$ as the even numbers, with binary expansions for membership in the usual way.
(Edit: I slightly misread your description, so my $G$ is actually slightly different from what you gave.  An even number represents the set of positions of 1’s in its binary expansion — but do we count positions with the numbers of $\CT$ or of $\PA$?  I mean the former; so the membership of $\CT$ is interpreted as the $\PA$-predicate “$n \in_G m$” defined as “$n = 2k+1$, $m$ is even, and the $(k+1)$st binary digit of $m$ is $1$.”  Digit positions are indexed from 0, so the $i$th digit is the coefficient of $2^i$.)
The composite $G \circ F : \PA \to \CT \to \PA$ reinterprets $\PA$ in itself as the odd numbers with the standard order; it’s easy to see this is definably isomorphic to the identity interpretation.
So it remains to show $F \circ G : \CT \to \PA \to \CT$ is definably isomorphic to the identity interpretation of $\CT$.  $F \circ G$ reinterprets numbers as odd numbers, and sets as even numbers.  Assuming $\CT$ proves full induction (which I don’t immediately see how to show, but you seem to claim it in the question), it’s not hard to define the intuitively-clear isomorphism between this and the identity interpretation. Numbers map to corresponding odd numbers by doubling, of course; then we can map sets to their codes $S \mapsto 2 \sum_{i \in S} 2^i$ by induction on cardinality $|S|$, and conversely we map even numbers to the sets they code by comprehension, $2k \mapsto \{ i < k \mid \lfloor k/2^i \!\rfloor\ \text{odd} \}$.
So this gives a conceptually clear bi-interpretation.  But it turns out that this can be automatically bumped up to a synonymy, by Corollary 5.3 of Friedman–Visser 2014, When bi-interpretability implies synonymy, since our $G$ is in their terminology “direct” — it interprets the total domain of $\CT$ (i.e. the union $\N_\CT \cup \S_\CT$) precisely as the total domain of $\PA$, $\N_\PA$.  And chasing through their proof, it shows us how to define the synonymy concretely: We keep $G$ as is, and modify $F$ to an isomorphic interpretation $F' : \PA \to \CT$, which interprets $\N_\PA$ not just as the numbers $\N_\CT$ but (as required for directness) as the total domain $\N_\CT + \S_\CT$, and then interprets the structure of $\PA$ on that by transporting the arithmetic structure of $\N_\CT$ along the definable isomorphism $(\N_\CT + \S_\CT) \cong \N_\CT$ that we constructed above to show that $F \circ G \cong \mathrm{id}_{\CT}$.

Just to make sure before going through it. I see you mentioning even numbers unleashed? When interpreting $\sf CT$ in $\sf PA$ we are using all the odd numbers but not all the evens, we are only using the evens whom their halves are sets of odd numbers by Ackermann's interpretation, those are not all the evens, since some evens have their halves being sets that can have evens among their elements by Ackermann's interpretation. Just to make sure, was that taken into consideration in your argument.

@ZuhairAl-Johar: Ah, good catch: I definitely mean all the evens; I realise the interpretation I had in mind is slightly different from the one you described.  I’ll edit my answer to show the one I had in mind!

which even number will correspond to the set ${1,3}$ in your system? We have $1=2\times 0+1$ so the $0+1$ position must be $1$ and we have $3=2\times1+1$ so the $1+1$ position must be $1$, so this would be a number whose binary expansion is $11$, but this is taken to be $3$?

Perhaps your binary assignment doesn't have a zero index so $11$ is taken to stand for $2^1+2^2 = 6$. I think this must be mentioned to avoid confusion.

@ZuhairAl-Johar: I don’t quite follow your counterexample, since you’re not clear whether you mean the 1 and 3 of CT or of PA.  Under my interpretation F, the set {1,3} of CT will correspond to the even number 10100 in PA (I’m writing all even PA-numbers in binary), since it has 1’s in positions 2 and 4 (i.e. 1+1 and 3+1).  The even number whose F-members are the 1 and 3 of PA will correspond to the CT-set {1,2}, so to the even number 1100.  Another example: the CT-set {0,1,2,5} will be represented by 1001110, with 1’s in positions 1, 2, 3, and 6, and members the PA-numbers 3, 5, 7, 11.

Oh — I see your next comment; yes, the confusion is just that I’m indexing digit positions from 0, not from 1.  So by “the $i$th digit”, I mean the coefficient of $2^i$.  I had hoped the formulas I gave later would make this clear enough.

hmmm.. I shall follow your exact definition, the set ${1,3}$ of $\sf CT$ is to be an interpreted by an even number in $\sf PA$ and this would have the binary expansion of $110$. Per your definition when $n=1= 2 \times 0 + 1$ so $k=0$ and so per your definition $1$ must be put at $k+1=0+1=1$ so it is the the $1st$ position in the binary number but this position is the second appearing from the right, so it is $...10$, also when $n=3=2k+1$ so $k=1$ and so we must have $1$ at $k+1=1+1=2$ position, which is the third digit from the right, so ${1,3} = 110$. And I think this is correct.

every even number in $\sf PA$ has a binary expansion where the first digit appearing on the right (i.e. at the zeroth position) is $0$. And per your definition of $\in_F$ (which I think should be $\in_G$), all those elements can only be $odds$ since to be an element $i$ represented by $1$ at position $p$ of the binary expansion, we must have $i=2(p-1) +1$, and so all sets of odds would be even numbers and all evens are sets of odd. Nice! To avoid confusion in the last comment I meant the binary expansion of ${1,3}$ is $110$ but this is the even number $6$.

Thanks for this brilliant proof!
